# Name of a ratio using a variance-covariance matrix of regression coefficients for main effects and interaction effects

Tags: variance, interaction, covariance

I consider a linear model with an interaction term.
Y = b0 + b1*X + b2*Z + b3*X*Z

X, Z are the independent variables. b1 to b3 are the regression coefficients. The variances of b1 and b3 are s11 and s33, respectively; the covariance of b1 and b3 is s13. Is there a name for s13 / (sqrt(s11) * sqrt(33))? It looks like the formula for the correlation coefficient, but it is not called the correlation coefficient, is it? If anyone knows what it is called, I would appreciate it if you could enlighten me!